# Asp.Net MVC Razor can not find my custom HtmlHelper helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I created a helper method for the HtmlHelper class:

```
namespace MyExampleApp.Infrastructure
{
    public static class LanguageHelper
    {
        public static HtmlString GenerateLocalizedAnchor(this HtmlHelper helper, string language, string innerText)
        {
           //Code will go here...
        }
    }
}
```

I imported the namespace in the View:

```
@using MyExampleApp.Infrastructure;
```

I added the namespace to the web.config file in the Views folder:

```
<add namespace="MyExampleApp.Infrastructure"/>
```

Even added to the web.config in the root folder too. I read many topics on Stackoverflow, every answer were the same: add the namespace to the web.config in the View folder.

I have been searching for hours. I have restarted Visual Web Developer Express many-many times, cleaned, rebuilt the build. According to the found topics on StackOverflow, everything is "perfect" in my code, but the Razor view still does not find my helper method. What else should I do?

UPDATE

The web.config in the Views folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MyExampleApp.Infrastructure"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The using statements in the class of the custom helper method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

Also I switched the HtmlString return value to MvcHtmlString, but the Razor view still does not see it.

Comment: Show us your `using` statements in the file.

Comment: Please post your web config in your Views folder. It might just be are referencing your html helper incorrectly. Also show us your using statements in your class.

Comment: It is solved, it was my bad. I tried to invoke the method by the HtmlHelper class as a static method, and not by the HtmlHelper instance of the View. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that your return type is an HtmlString. That should be changed to MvcHtmlString. I will be able to provide a better answer once you've posted the stuff requested.